# Locking up when using USB terminal between MacBook AIr and RPi2

Tags: usb, serial, communication

When I communicate with RPi2 using USB (pin 6,8,10) to my MacBook Air using Terminal, it works fine until I use nano to edit python. Then the communication gets scrambled (what happens is not what I type on keyboard) within about 10-15 seconds and finally freezes completely. I can usually recover just by unplugging the USB from my computer for a few seconds, plugging in again, and then typing

```
$ screen /dev/cu.usbserial 115200
```

again. So it seems like a communication problem, but I'm curious why it always degrades over 10-15 seconds before freezing, and why it seems to happen only after I start editing with nano!

I was told this is not uncommon with Mac and that I can try WiFi, but I would really like to stick with USB.

Is this a known problem? Any suggestions what I can try to get the USB connection to work without freezing?

(help with tags for this question appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you disabled the serial console on the Pi? It is possible that the Python serial and console I/O are both trying to communicate. This can be disabled using `raspi-config` (I don't have access to a Pi at the moment, so can't check which menu, but it shouldn't be hard to find.)

PS I have used serial from my Mac to Pi without issue, but rarely do so - it is MUCH easier to use `ssh`.

Comment: OK thanks, let me "find out" which means ask someone here to show me how to find out. Stay tuned...  btw [does '`ssh`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/unix.md) use ethernet cable connection?

Comment: @uhoh I am not sure I understand the comment. Just run `sudo raspi-config` and look through the options. You can run `ssh` over any IP connection - direct ethernet, through a router or WiFi.

Comment: Actually this is all very helpful (and news) to me! Thank you @Milliways.